# Show final price (full price) of configurable products variations

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product

I have a configurable product with 2 variations:

- Variation I (Default): Dimension 4.5cm Price $1.81
- Variation II: Dimension 7cm Price $1.81 + R$1.01 = $2.82

I need remove `+ $1.01` and `show` ***$2.82*** on dropdown variations.

I need to show full price of all products variations.

How to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial extension by Best4Mage that does this https://www.best4mage.co.uk/configurable-products-use-simple-price.html

It's not free but I have never had any problems with it